# flash as3 - access stage outside document class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to add a keyboard event listener to the stage, to detect when a user clicks the left or right arrow keys. But this listener is called from inside a class file which is imported into the document class, therefore I think it doesn't know what "stage" refers to. How do I solve this?

This is my code:

Document Class: AugmentedReality.as :

```
package {
  import examples.PlaneVid_Carousel;

  public function AugmentedReality(){
    addChild (new PlaneVid_Carousel())
  }
}
```

PlaneVid_Carousel.as {

```
  package examples {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class PlaneVid_Carousel extends Sprite {

      public function PlaneVid_Carousel(){
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown
      }

      protected function keyPressedDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        //DO STUFF
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your keyboard listener after PlaneVid_Carousel has been added to the stage, then the stage will be accessible.

```
public function PlaneVid_Carousel() 
{
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
}

protected function keyPressedDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    //DO STUFF
}
```

I always use this init method for my DisplayObjects, and it is the default template of a DisplayObject for FlashDevelop.

Comment: @mheavens, forget what I said. I totally overlooked the fact that your class is in fact a Sprite. What @adam says is the appropriate way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix would be to add a static property on the document class, that for this example is called MyApp.as. You assign a value to the globalStage property by setting it at a decent point in time, which for most cases in the document class can be the constructor:

```
public class MyApp extends Sprite {
    public static var globalStage:Stage;
    //...

    public function MyApp() {
        globalStage = stage;
    }
}
```

After that you can access the stage from anywhere by importing the document class and calling this snippet:

```
MyApp.globalStage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);
```

Now it doesn't have to be a property of the the document class, maybe a dedicated class like `StageProxy` would be more clear, and you can still assign it from the document class.

```
public function MyApp() {
    StageProxy.stage = stage;
}
```

And access it from anywhere:

```
StageProxy.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);
```

This is still not what I'd call 'clean' or 'pretty', but it gets the job done.